# Forcing gulp build?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to create a distribution version of my angular project using `gulp build`, however, when I run the command, it fails with a whopping 146 errors, many of which seem to be strictly style enforcement.

Is there a way to force gulp to ignore these linting errors and forcefully create a dist version?

I am using `gulp-cli 1.2.2`.

The app was scaffolded using yeoman. Here's my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/uhuKLsdk) and my [gulpfile.js](https://pastebin.com/uTJW1L52).

And lastly, the output after running `gulp build`:

```
[21:56:28] Requiring external module babel-register
[21:56:29] Using gulpfile ~/code/proverbial/client/gulpfile.babel.js
[21:56:29] Starting 'lint'...
[21:56:29] Starting 'styles'...
[21:56:29] Starting 'scripts'...
[21:56:29] Starting 'images'...
[21:56:29] Starting 'fonts'...
[21:56:29] Starting 'extras'...
(node:12187) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[21:56:30] Finished 'images' after 239 ms
[21:56:31] Finished 'extras' after 1.01 s
[21:56:31] Finished 'styles' after 1.51 s
[21:56:31] Finished 'fonts' after 1.24 s
[21:56:31] 
/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/app.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
  19:35  error  Unexpected trailing comma                      comma-dangle
  31:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/polyfills.js
   1:0   error  String prototype is read only, properties should not be added  no-extend-native
   1:28  error  Missing "use strict" statement                                 strict
   4:1   error  Expected { after 'if' condition                                curly
  11:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found                  eol-last
  11:1   error  Missing semicolon                                              semi

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/routes.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
  52:22  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  54:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/data.factory.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:32  error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  14:21  error  getData was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  14:28  error  Unexpected trailing comma                      comma-dangle
  24:46  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  26:29  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  41:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/firstLetter.filter.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:31  error  There should be no space before ','            comma-spacing
   6:33  error  Filter was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
  10:41  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  20:9   error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  22:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/interceptor.factory.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                         no-undef
   6:36  error  factory was used before it was defined           no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  factory was used before it was defined           no-use-before-define
  13:21  error  request was used before it was defined           no-use-before-define
  14:26  error  requestError was used before it was defined      no-use-before-define
  15:22  error  response was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
  16:27  error  responseError was used before it was defined     no-use-before-define
  31:34  error  Missing semicolon                                semi
  35:26  error  response is already declared in the upper scope  no-shadow
  41:34  error  Missing semicolon                                semi
  45:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found    eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/lang.service.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:30  error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  13:8   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
  13:60  error  key is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
  20:21  error  getLang was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  21:21  error  setLang was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  28:9   error  Unnecessary semicolon                          no-extra-semi
  28:9   error  Found unexpected statement after a return      no-unreachable
  34:16  error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
  34:68  error  key is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
  40:9   error  Unnecessary semicolon                          no-extra-semi
  40:9   error  Found unexpected statement after a return      no-unreachable
  42:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/maxLength.filter.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:29  error  There should be no space before ','            comma-spacing
   6:31  error  Filter was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
  10:12  error  Expected { after 'if' condition                curly
  13:12  error  Expected { after 'if' condition                curly
  13:31  error  "value" is not defined                         no-undef
  14:12  error  Expected { after 'if' condition                curly
  20:42  error  Infix operators must be spaced                 space-infix-ops
  20:79  error  Infix operators must be spaced                 space-infix-ops
  27:9   error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  29:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/onKey.directive.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:28  error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
  10:23  error  $timeout is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
  12:18  error  link was used before it was defined            no-use-before-define
  19:25  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
  26:20  error  Unexpected alert                               no-alert
  26:28  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  31:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/onScroll.directive.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:39  error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
  12:18  error  link was used before it was defined            no-use-before-define
  16:8   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                    no-trailing-spaces
  19:39  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  27:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/proverbs.service.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:36  error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Service was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  10:42  error  CONFIG is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  14:25  error  getProverbs was used before it was defined     no-use-before-define
  14:36  error  Unexpected trailing comma                      comma-dangle
  19:30  error  options is defined but never used              no-unused-vars
  23:42  error  Missing semicolon                              semi
  27:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/shared/randomBackgroundColor.directive.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:44  error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Directive was used before it was defined       no-use-before-define
  10:23  error  $timeout is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
  12:18  error  link was used before it was defined            no-use-before-define
  27:24  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
  27:37  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
  27:47  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
  27:57  error  Strings must use singlequote                   quotes
  33:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/components/navbar/navbar.directive.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                          no-undef
   6:29  error  Directive was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  Directive was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
   8:50  error  A space is required after ','                     comma-spacing
  12:24  error  Missing space before value for key "templateUrl"  key-spacing
  13:18  error  link was used before it was defined               no-use-before-define
  17:8   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                       no-trailing-spaces
  18:38  error  attrs is defined but never used                   no-unused-vars
  20:12  error  Trailing spaces not allowed                       no-trailing-spaces
  29:18  error  Missing semicolon                                 semi
  30:13  error  Missing semicolon                                 semi
  34:18  error  Missing semicolon                                 semi
  35:13  error  Missing semicolon                                 semi
  38:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found     eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/components/proverbs/proverb.ctrl.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                       no-undef
   6:35  error  proverbCtrl was used before it was defined     no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  proverbCtrl was used before it was defined     no-use-before-define
   9:36  error  $stateParams is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
  15:8   error  activate was used before it was defined        no-use-before-define
  18:25  error  The '__proto__' property is deprecated         no-proto
  21:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/components/proverbs/proverbs.cut-up.ctrl.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                         no-undef
   6:40  error  proverbCutUpCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  proverbCutUpCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
   9:41  error  $stateParams is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  16:26  error  getFirstHalf was used before it was defined      no-use-before-define
  16:49  error  getSecondHalf was used before it was defined     no-use-before-define
  18:8   error  activate was used before it was defined          no-use-before-define
  20:17  error  getCutUp is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  20:33  error  settings is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  24:16  error  before is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
  25:16  error  after is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
  61:25  error  The '__proto__' property is deprecated           no-proto
  64:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found    eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/components/proverbs/proverbs.detail.ctrl.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                          no-undef
   6:41  error  proverbDetailCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  proverbDetailCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
  13:58  error  Missing semicolon                                 semi
  16:8   error  activate was used before it was defined           no-use-before-define
  19:25  error  The '__proto__' property is deprecated            no-proto
  22:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found     eol-last

/home/james/code/proverbial/client/app/scripts/components/proverbs/proverbs.list.ctrl.js
   4:4   error  "angular" is not defined                        no-undef
   6:39  error  proverbListCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
   8:4   error  proverbListCtrl was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
   9:40  error  $stateParams is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
  17:40  error  Missing semicolon                               semi
  18:9   error  Missing semicolon                               semi
  20:8   error  activate was used before it was defined         no-use-before-define
  23:25  error  The '__proto__' property is deprecated          no-proto
  26:1   error  Newline required at end of file but not found   eol-last

✖ 146 problems (146 errors, 0 warnings)

[21:56:31] 'lint' errored after 2.05 s
[21:56:31] ESLintError in plugin 'gulp-eslint'
Message:
    Failed with 146 errors
[21:56:31] Finished 'scripts' after 1.61 s
```

For further analysis, removing `lint` from the `build` task, while indeed skipping the previously mentioned errors, results in the following `Unhandled 'error' event`:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2103:9)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2630:9)
    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2792:19)
    at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2827:24)
    at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2832:20)
    at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2856:20)
    at expression (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2875:20)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2314:55)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2178:20)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2136:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2904:23)
    at Object.parse (eval at <anonymous> (/home/james/code/proverbial/client/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2915:7)
```

**EDIT:** adding [gulpfile.js](https://pastebin.com/uTJW1L52) as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I was able to solve the problem.

Most of the linting rules I was having trouble with can be edited on the `eslint.json` file that comes in the [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) npm package.

I turned off some of the more over-zealous linting errors and ended up going with this [eslint.json](https://pastebin.com/JwUgcZW3) configuration.

I did not ignore the following:

1. **"angular" is not defined**: I solved by adding `var angular = window.angular || {};` to the beginning of all my angular components.
2. **Newline required at end of file but not found**: I solved by tweaking the settings on Visual Studio Code. Setting `files.trimTrailingWhitespace` and auto-formatting the affect files solved the problem. Here's [settings.json](https://pastebin.com/0QL9H9qy) for reference.
3. **Trailing spaces not allowed**: Same as above. Setting `files.insertFinalNewline` to `true` solved the problem.

The rest of the errors I've either fixed manually, such as the missing semi-colons, or decided to ignore by downgrading them to a warning. You can do this by editing the number after the error code in your `eslit.json` file as I mentioned above. For example, `"no-use-before-define": 0` will completely ignore this ocurrence. Setting it to `1` will only log a warning and a `2` will interupt the execution of the task.

---

After dealing with the linting errors, `gulp build` was still erroring out by trying to parse `html` files.

Some investigation led me to [this thread](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/572) which solved the issue for me. There was a bug with `gulp-if` in the `generator-webapp` package, which I used to scaffold my application. To quote from the thread:

> After updating gulp-if to 2.0.2, the issue no longer exists.

I can now run `gulp build` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to fix this:

1. You can remove the lint task from your build task in your gulpfile
2. Change your linting rules to ignore these errors
3. Fix the errors
4. Use the `--continue` flag to tell Gulp to continue running even if errors are thrown: `gulp build --continue`

Comment: I tried the `--continue` flag before and it did nothing for me. The output is exactly the same. Fixing the errors is what I'm trying to avoid. When I remove the `lint` task from gulp build I get another error, which I can add to my post above.

Comment: I would guess that's a problem with the gulpfile, can you post that or provide a link to it?

Comment: Just added a link to pastebin with my gulpfile.

Comment: Since this is a parse error, there is likely a syntax error somewhere. It could be in a file you are importing, or it may be caused by one of the linting errors above (they all seem fairly benign though, so it's hard to say). The preferred course of action is of course to fix all of the errors, but since you're trying to avoid that I recommend using [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util) to find which file is throwing this parse error.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the errors now, and already stuck at number one... how is angular not defined if it is saved as a dependency on bower and it works perfectly fine in my dev environment? I'm not sure how to start debugging this.

Comment: Apparently adding var `angular = require('angular');` to the top of the file fixed the problem.

Comment: I've fixed all the linting errors, now gulp build blows up with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (<)`